What's that movie about a house full of traps

I have watched it on TV when I was a little boy in the 70s. Maybe somewhere in between 1975-1980. So the production date must have been before the 70-s or early 70-s.
The whole story took place after WWII. So the movie must have been made after 1950.
I am almost sure it was a French movie.
Black and white (Film Noir) maybe.

It tells the story of a man, a robber, who tries to enter a house in order to steal a statuette (I guess it was a gold statuette, very precious, may Incas, Mayan, African...). The house was empty, but it was full with traps for potential robbers. In fact it was mostly a single actor movie - showing his advance in the house and his overcoming of the traps. There was (one of the traps) a big wardrobe, full with lead, which fell over him and nearly killed him. Then a woman came a helped him get out from under the wardrobe. He succeeded to reach the statuette but I guess he died on the electric wheelchair  (the last trap?). This was how the movie ended at least - he sitting on the chair, "driving" around the room with the statuette in the middle...   

What year\decade was it from, approximately?

Unfortunatelly I have no idea about any more details. I have watched it on TV when I was a little boy in the 70s. Maybe somewhere in between 1975-1980. So the production date must have been before the 70-s or early 70-s. And I am almost sure it was a French movie.

... and the whole story took place after WWII. So the movie must have been made after 1950...

It remind me of Home Alone (1990) but the year does not match and there is a boy :p
